# how to hide menu option with javascript while calling menu as mysql fetch array

Tags: javascript, php

There are lot of answers about dropdown menus. But I'm calling menu items from database.

If i click some menu item (`$table[0]`), content (`' . $table[0] . ' - content`) shows and if I click again, content disappear. So far so good.

Problem is, if some content is already opened and I click another menu item, I get opened both contents. How to allow open only last selected and still remain toggle function...?

I have tried many things, this is one of them:

```
<?php
include 'connect_database.php';  
$result = mysqli_query($con, "show tables"); 
while($table = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
echo '<button onclick="' . $table[0] . 'myFunction()">' . $table[0] . '</button><br />
     <div id="' . $table[0] . '" style="display:none;"   class="tabcontent">' . $table[0] . ' - content</div>
     <script>
     function ' . $table[0] . 'myFunction() {
     var x = document.getElementById("' . $table[0] . '");
     if (x.style.display === "none") {
     x.style.display = "block";
     } else {
     x.style.display = "none";
     }}
     </script>';
} 
?>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: without php it would not be a problem... :/

Comment: share your javascript code

Comment: Abdul, what do you mean share code? I put javascript code inside echo in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't keep track of all the menus that are created.
Also `myFunction` is the same for all of them so probable it is enough to define only one :)
I would do it like this:

```
<?php
   include 'connect_database.php';  

   $result = mysqli_query($con, "show tables"); 
   while($table = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
       $name = $table[0];
       echo "<button onclick='myFunction(\"$name\")'>$name</button><br /><div id='$name'  style='display:none;'   class='tabcontent'>$name - content</div>";
   }
?>
<script>
  function myFunction(id) {
     registerId(id);
     hideAll(id);

     var x = document.getElementById(id),
         s = x.style.display;

      x.style.display = (s === "none") ? "block" : "none";
  }
  // register a new id so we know what to hide when needed
  function registerId (id) {
    var m = window.myMenus = window.myMenus || [];

    if(m.indexOf(id) === -1) {
       m.push(id);
    }
  }

  // hide all registered menus except the id
  function hideAll(id) {
    var m = window.myMenus = window.myMenus || [],
        i, l=m.length;

    for(i=0;i<l;i++){
      if(m[i] == id) continue;
      var x = document.getElementById(m[i]);

      x.style.display = 'none';
    }

  }
 </script>
```

OR you can track the last opened one and close only that :D

```
php code remains the same as before
<script>
  function myFunction(id) {
      var x,old;

     if(old = window.lastOpenId) {
        x = document.getElementById(old);
        x.style.display = "none";
        delete window.lastOpenId; 
     }

     if(id != old) {
        x = document.getElementById(id);
        x.style.display = "block";
        window.lastOpenId = id;
     }
  }
</script>
```

Note that in both cases the `script` is outside the `while` loop and outside the `php` code so it needs to be printed only once.

Comment: pefect! Thank you. Own you some beer :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you have to close all elements when an element is clicked. I'll go for class selection hack, although it can be done multiple ways:

```
<?php
include 'connect_database.php';  
$result = mysqli_query($con, "show tables"); 
while($table = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
echo '<button onclick="' . $table[0] . 'myFunction()">' . $table[0] . '</button><br />
     <div id="' . $table[0] . '" style="display:none;"   class="tabcontent">' . $table[0] . ' - content</div>
     <script>
     function ' . $table[0] . 'myFunction() {
         var x = document.getElementById("' . $table[0] . '");
         if (x.style.display === "none") {
             x.style.display = "block";
         } else {
             x.style.display = "none";
         }
         // Select all elements
         var els = document.querySelectorAll(".tabcontent);
         for (var i = 0, el; el = els[i]; i++) {
             if (el != x) { // Do not hide current element
                 x.style.display = "none";
             }
         }
     }
     </script>';
} 
?>
```

Protip: Keep your indentation clean.

Comment: Thanks a lof for your answer Jorge. I`m afraid it is impossible to open any content now. I need fresh air and I`ll try imrove it.

Comment: @MichalKotus Check you Chrome (I guess) console with F12 and look for any errors.